# How to disable Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA clipboard management on OSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) for managing my clipboard on OSX. The clipboard stacking/mgt feature of Android Studio interferes with ClipMenu's features and I'm looking for a way to disable this feature in Android Studio. Does anyone have experience with this?

I already tried:

- Removing Copy & Paste Shortcuts in Android Studio (to maybe get the system behaviour back) -> Copy & Paste disabled in Android Studio
- Setting "Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard" to 0 or 1
- apart from that I did not find any settings in Android Studio's Preferences when searching for "clipboard"

I want to avoid using Android Studio's clipboard stacking as I want to use a consistent shortcut for "Paste from history" throughout my OS.

Cheers!

**Update**
As Android Studio tends to overwrite the changes on update, I created a mini-bash script to re-"fix" the clipboard (on OS X; just adjust the path for other OSes):

```
echo "ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=true" >> /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties
```

Comment: Mind sharing the bash script?

Comment: See "update"  above ;) @Nxt3

Comment: That's not really a script. You made it sound like you had a way to autoapply it on AS updates. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, if one could solve that with some kind of on-update-hook, that would be awesome!

Comment: this is android studio's most annoying "feature"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right click on "Application/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app" choose "Show Package Contents", edit  "bin/idea.properties", add this property "ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True", restart IntelliJ IDEA.

There is a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114252) for this problem with additional information.

Comment: Thx yole !!!! - file is at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties