# How to clear android studio ide clipboard

Tags: android, android-studio

While my Android Studio IDE was open, I was filling up some sensitive form in browser and copy-pasted some sensitive data into the form. Now that data is registered into android studio ide clipboard. How can I delete the same? Hopefully android studio will provide some switch that allows disabling clipboard history feature

Comment: would File - Invalidate Caches not work ?

Comment: It might help [How to disable android studio intellij idea clipboard management on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27949064/how-to-disable-android-studio-intellij-idea-clipboard-management-on-osx)